# Extract ID attribute from structured text file for all records with a specific type attribute

Tags: text-processing

UPDATE:
I partly solved it by first looking at the whole configuration in this device. Then used this command: `egrep -wir 'peer' test* | uniq | sort | cut -d\  -f3 ~/test.txt`.

- And this is the result I got:

  ```
  neighbour
  00.000.0.000 (the IP address, I just put all 0s as an example)
  abc-hub
  nib
  SEC-INC-PA-int Azure_ER_key
  abc23
  ijf689
  jkl412
  kli456
  peer
  ```

How can I filter the them so I only get this as an output?:

```
abc23
ijf689
jkl412
kli456
```

---

I'm supposed to get a list of all routers at a particular customer grouped by hub in particular locations. Let's say the customer is called `test`.

- An example of the config file for the customer looks like this:

  ```
  abc23   interface: Tunnel000
          Type:Hub
  aqw789  interface: Tunnel222
          Type:Spoke
  ert458  interface: Tunnel111
          Type:Spoke
  ijf689  interface: Tunnel333
          Type:Hub
  jkl412  interface: Tunnel000
          Type:Hub/Spoke
  kli456  interface: Tunnel111
          Type:Hub
  ```

I tried to use this command

```
egrep -wir 'hub' test* cut -d : -f1 | uniq
```

But didn't get the expected result.

I want the output to look like this:

```
abc23
ijf689
jkl412
kli456
```

FYI, I'm using GNU. Linux version 3.2.0-6-amd64; gcc version 4.9.2

I would really appreciate your help! Thank you! :)

Comment: Welcome to the site. So, you want to look for all records where the `Type` attribute has the value `Hub` in a file called `test`, is that right?

Comment: @AdminBee yes it's correct

Comment: Is that the actual configuration file, or has it been processed in some way? What I want to find out is whether the data is available in a common structured language such as YAML or TOML or similar, for which there exist parsers.

Comment: @Kusalananda that is the actual configuration.

Comment: Your update contains data not present in the example that you are actually showing. Please update.

Answer (score 0):

Read `man grep awk`, and do something like:

```
grep -B1 -w -i "hub" test | \
  grep -i "interface:" | \
  awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: I tried to use your command but it shows ``-bash:  : command not found``

Comment: Typographical mistake on your part? Did you include the ":" from the word "like:"?

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
grep -B 1 "Type:Hub" test* | grep "interface:" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: It unfotunately didn't give any result.

Comment: You may combine the last `grep` and `awk` like `awk '/interface:/ { print $1 }'`.

Comment: @EllaWidya You will notice that it works on your example data. If your actual data is different, then please update the sample data in your question. We can't guess what your data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The following `awk` program should do:

```
awk '$1~/^Type/{split($1,f,/:/);t=f[2]} $2~/^interface/{if (id && t~/Hub/) print id; id=$1; t=""} END{if (id && t~/Hub/) print id}' test.txt
```

This will assume the format is strictly as shown, with no additional spaces (in particular around the `:` of the `Type` statement and the `/`).

- On lines where the first "Word" starts with `Type`, we split the line at the `:` into the array `f` and store the second entry as variable `t`.
- On lines where the second "Word" starts with `interface`, we store the first "Word" (the router ID). Before that, we check if a router ID was already stored from a previous record. If so, we print the previous ID if the previous type contains the word "Hub". We also reset `t` to ensure no "left-over" information messes up the parsing.
- At end-of-file we do the same.

Comment: I tried your command and it gave zero answer :(
the customer name is just ``test`` without being saved in a file, so not ``test.txt``
Btw I have to do it on the configuration mode ``~/configs/routers/configs$``

Comment: @EllaWidya I don't understand this comment. What do you mean by "without being saved in a file"?

Comment: the name is ``test``, not ``test.txt``. Maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: @EllaWidya Well, if the file is actually called `test`, then of course you should use the filename `test` instead of `test.txt`. Only - you used `test*` in the example you showed, so I assumed there is more than one file for the customer `test`, like `test-1.txt`, `test-2.txt` and so on. Also, please be sure to add all relevant information to the question.

Comment: I partly solved it by first looking at the whole configuration in this device. Then used this command: `egrep -wir 'peer' test* | uniq | sort | cut -d\  -f3 ~/test.txt`.

* And this is the result I got:
    ```none
    neighbour
    00.000.0.000 (the IP address, I just put all 0s as an example)
    test-hub
    nib
    SEC-INC-PA-int Azure_ER_key
    abc23
    ijf689
    jkl412
    kli456
    peer```

How can I filter the them so I only get this as an output?:
```none
abc23
ijf689
jkl412
kli456
```

Comment: @EllaWidya It would help if the data in the question was "as real as possible" and not entirely made up, just to be able to catch edge cases and oddities in solutions that we provide.  This solution (as all the other ones) work on the data that you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
sed -e 'N; y/\n/ /' -e '/Type:Hub/!d; s/ .*//' file
```

This joins the pair of `interface:`-`Type:` lines together, so that after `N; y/\n/ /` the `sed` contains lines like

```
abc23   interface: Tunnel000         Type:Hub
aqw789  interface: Tunnel222         Type:Spoke
ert458  interface: Tunnel111         Type:Spoke
ijf689  interface: Tunnel333         Type:Hub
jkl412  interface: Tunnel000         Type:Hub/Spoke
kli456  interface: Tunnel111         Type:Hub
```

(`N` appends the next line to the buffer and `y/\n/ /` replaces the embedded newline between the two lines with a space.)

The rest of the `sed` command deletes all lines that does not match `Type:Hub` and then everything from the first space character on the lines remaining. The `/Type:Hub/!d` deletes unwanted lines, and `s/ .*//` truncates the lines at the first space.

What you get as the final result is

```
abc23
ijf689
jkl412
kli456
```